# Different cookies for domain and subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, loopbackjs

I'm creating applications with NodeJS (LoopBack).

My main app is hosted on: **domain.com** and additional application -
 **app.domain.com**.

By using `res.cookie(name, value, [, options])` I setup cookies at the client side with the next line,

`res.cookie('testName', 'testValue', {maxAge: 123456, secure: true, domain: 'domain.com'})`.

When I try to setup cookies with this line, instead of **domain.com** I get **.domain.com** and cookies are shared between main domain and subdomain.

The problem is that I need to setup cookies separately. One cookies for **domain.com** another one for **app.domain.com**.

Thanks!

Comment: So....be more explicit `domain: 'app.domain.com'` when you need to be?

Comment: @James thanks. I have tried `domain: 'domain.com'` for one cookies and `domain: 'app.domain.com'` for another one. But the problem is that I can see cookies from `domain.com` on `app.domain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

A very informative guide is [here](https://www.mxsasha.eu/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/) but I'll summarize the relevant point:

- If you manually specify the domain (`domain.com`) it **automatically** gets promoted to `.domain.com`
- However, if you don't supply any domain whatsoever, it defaults to the current domain **without the `.`**.

If you want `domain.com` to not share cookies with `app.domain.com`, you just need to set the cookie **without specifying the domain**.